# firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.droidbane.recipe.database.models.Categories

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**My Database:**

[image]

**My Logcat:**

```
2022-07-31 16:04:14.850 6729-6729/com.droidbane.recipe E/ghj: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.droidbane.recipe.database.models.Categories
2022-07-31 16:04:14.851 6729-6729/com.droidbane.recipe E/ghj: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.droidbane.recipe.database.models.Categories
2022-07-31 16:04:14.852 6729-6729/com.droidbane.recipe E/ghj: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.droidbane.recipe.database.models.Categories
2022-07-31 16:04:14.852 6729-6729/com.droidbane.recipe E/ghj: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.droidbane.recipe.database.models.Categories
```

**My Code :**

```
public void getAllCategories() {
        myRef = database.getReference("categories").child(categoryID);

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                categoriesArrayList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    try {
                        Categories categories = data.getValue(Categories.class);

                        assert categories != null;

                        categories.setKey(data.getKey());

                        categoriesArrayList.add(categories);
                    }catch (Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e("ghj", String.valueOf(throwable) );
                    }

                }

                System.out.println(categoriesArrayList);

                recipeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
}
```

**I wanted to do:**

I want to give the information of the category whose id I have specified for the RecyclerView.

I just want to get the information of the data selected with id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference you build here:

```
myRef = database.getReference("categories").child(categoryID);
```

This points to a single category in your database, so when you then get the data for that category and loop over its child nodes in `onDataChange`, your `data` become each of the individual properties of that category (`image`, `imageTwo`, `key`, etc). So when you then call `data.getValue(Categories.class)`, you're trying to convert the value of an individual property to a `Categories` object, which doesn't work.

The solution is to remove the loop from your `onDataChange`, and instead get the single category in the snapshot with:

```
Categories categories = snapshot.getValue(Categories.class)
```